# objective c iPhone side scroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was making a game and I did the side scrolling like this: if the player get past 150,
the player stops moving and the background starts moving. But thats very annoying with placing objects in the game. Isn't there a better way to do this? I do **not** want to use cocos2D.

### #

See Also

> [How to implement circular side scrolling in my game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661220/how-to-implement-circular-side-scrolling-in-my-game)